# Is it possible to convince MySQL to use an index with USE INDEX FOR JOIN, even after no longer joining?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

It's been a long day, but I've been wresting with a query which wont use an index, and thus takes much longer than it should.  I stumbled upon `USE INDEX FOR JOIN`, but it didn't improve anything.

**Then I reverted it back to the original query.**

Now it's decided to use that index, instead of the previous full table scan and it's down from 17s to 1s.

Did I "convince" the query planner to use the index with `USE INDEX FOR JOIN`?

Comment: Without any query or table structure or `EXPLAIN {query}` this question isn't not worth asking. INDEX forcing should only happen in extreme and temporary cases.

Comment: could just be a changing of samples hit the right spot. No reason it couldn't revert. Details required. [suggested reading](https://www.slideshare.net/SvetaSmirnova/billion-goods-in-few-categories-how-histograms-save-a-life)

Comment: *Now it's decided to use that index* The table statistic refreshes. Next time simply execute ANALYZE TABLE.